# Storing and retrieving messages from a database

Tags: python, database, twilio, pythonanywhere

I am trying to set up a webhook on PythonAnywhere to connect to Twilio. I am essentially trying to create a very simple chatbot with if statements which choose a response based on the text message that comes in. I am now trying to add a databsae into the mix so that the response can also be based on previous texts as well. I have managed to set up the database but cant seem to get the text messages that are received to be stored in the database.

I have tried going on various tutorials and answer websites like this one but have not managed to get any of the potential solutions to work. They either break the code entirely so that no messages are sent in response or still nothing is stored in the database.

[Code currently used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0QDa.png)

```py
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from socket import gethostname

app = Flask(__name__)

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{databasename}".format(
    username="UrbanMissions",
    password="Hello123",
    hostname="UrbanMissions.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com",
    databasename="UrbanMissions$ClueNumber",
)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Reply(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "messages"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
content = db.Column(db.String(4096))

[...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    reply = Reply(content=request.values.get('Body', None)
    db.session.add(reply)
    db.session.commit()
    if 'liveconsole' not in gethostname():
        app.run()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])

def main():

    body = request.values.get('Body', None)
    text = body.lower()
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    if text.find("start") == 0:
```

This is the code that seems to cause all the problems

```
("$reply = Reply(content=request.values.get('Body', None)
$db.session.add(reply)
$db.session.commit()")
```

it is my attempt to add the message that was sent in to the messages database but this doesn't seem to work. Any advice on how to get this to work to add the incoming message to the database would be really appreciated. Also what the code to retrieve the message again from the database would really help.

Comment: always put code as text in question, not image. We can't copy and run code from image.

Comment: My apologies, had trouble understanding how to get stackoverflow to recognise it as code but seems to be working now.

Comment: The code you mention is inside the 'if __name__ == "__main__"` block, which is not executed for PythonAnywhere websites.  Shouldn't it be in your Twilio webhook handler?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I have tried putting the code in various locations (as I am fairly new to coding so didnt know where it belonged).